# swift show images in full screen from embedded page view controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have an embedded Page View Controller inside my VC.

What is the best solution to add a tap gesture on the image, so that it will open in a full screen with zoom enabled / paging between the images?

Should I try to animate this in my current VC or should I open it inside another VC?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: @random but what is the best approach?

Comment: are you using auto layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would animate the page view controller to fill the screen instead of adding a new `UIViewController`, here is why:

1. **Memory**: You already have the images loaded once, no need to create a new `UIViewController` and re-load again. Also adding another `UIViewController` to the stack isn't the end of the world but should be avoided if possible.
2. **Code**: You'v already written code to handle the content size and addition of images to the page controller. Copy and pasting into a new `UIViewController` would be extremely redundant.
3. **Animation**: If you wanted to animate the photo going to full screen the best way would be to animate the frame of the existing page controller. Just make sure to update the content size after animating.

Comment: Cant I just pass the images from my current VC to the next one? In that way I don't have to download them again

Comment: @KiwoTew yes I suppose so